# 403 Forbidden on ~/Sites symlink in /User/username/Documents folder. Can't seem to get past it

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, symlink

I know this sort of question has been asked many times, but I have tried the solutions I have found to no avail.

I have just set up amp on MacOS Sierra, and the ~/Sites folder works fine.

However, I have added a symlink to a folder in my Documents, lets say /User/username/Documents/website, but this folder doesn't show in the web browser and going to it directly is giving a 403 forbidden error.

I have tried setting permissions on the folder, but it still shows as the following...

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  staff  100  6 Jan 11:22 website -> /Users/username/Documents/website
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overcome this problem by setting the Apache user to my Mac account...

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
#User _www
#Group _www

User 'mac account'
Group staff
```